# Select tag and go to page option

Tags: javascript, html, select, onchange

Can anyone explain why below example does not work?
I'd like to impelment dropdown that will redirect to other sites based on the option selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/5swk8/6/

```
function go()
{
    window.location=document.getElementById("menu-dropdown").value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying as 'Uncaught ReferenceError: go is not defined' because the go() method is wrapped in onload. Change the wrap option to body, then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Frameworks & Extensions panel`, set `onLoad to No wrap - in <body>`.it will work

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/4R9Kx/)**

Answer (score 0):

Without a separate function

```
<select id="mySelect" onChange="document.location = this.value" value="GO">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="http://www.microsoft.com">Test</option>
</select>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2ekmM/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in redirecting the page. It is

```
window.location.href="";
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is right only thing you have move your go function inside body 
I updated your code in jsfiddle.

jsfiddle.net/mannejkumar/5swk8/11/

Comment: I am not able to post jsfiddle link